# periodic structure in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create a script to solve my problem, but I got stuck in one place.
So I have imported .txt file with 4x1 sized matrix (simplified to give an example in my case it might be 1209x1 matrix) which contains some coordinate X. And it's look like this:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
```

That's coordinates for one period, and I need to get one column for different number of periods N . Each period is the same and lenght=L

So you can do it manually by this script, for example for N=3 periods:

```
X=[X; X+L; X+2*L];
```

so for example if L=3

then i will get

```
0
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
7
8
9
```

it works well but it's not efficient in case if I need to work with number of periods let's say N=1000 or if I need to change their number quickly. Any solution to parameterize this operation so I can just put number for N and get X for N periods?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: description of my problem was a bit wrong (about arrays) so I've edited initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have MATLAB on this machine so I can't test, but the most straightforward implementation would be something like:

```
n = 1000;
L = 3;
nvalues = length(X); % Assuming X is your initial vector

newx = zeros(n*nvalues, 1); % Preallocate new array
for ii = 0:(n-1)
   startidx = (nvalues*ii) + 1;
   endidx   = nvalues*(ii+1);

   newx(startidx:endidx) = X + ii*L
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bsxfun` to create `X`, `X+L`, `X+2*L`, ... and then reshape it to a vector

```
>> F=bsxfun(@plus, X, (0:(N-1))*L)
F =
     0     3     6
     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9
>> X=F(:)
X =
     0
     1
     2
     3
     3
     4
     5
     6
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

or in a more concise form:

```
>> X=reshape(bsxfun(@plus, X, (0:(N-1))*L), [], 1)
X =
     0
     1
     2
     3
     3
     4
     5
     6
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

Comment: thank you! i've just started learning about matlab and all that info is very useful.